# Estimate the parameters of the normal distribution from which numbers are sampled

Tags: matlab, statistics, normal-distribution

Given a vector of numbers sampled from the normal distribution, how do I estimate the parameters (i.e. the mean and variance) of the normal distribution from which those numbers were sampled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Matlab function you are looking for is [`normfit`](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/stats/normfit.html). If you call `normfit` with only one argument `X`, it will give you 2 outputs, an estimate of the mean and of the standard deviation:

```
[muhat,sigmahat] = normfit(X)
```

where the `muhat` is the estimate of mean and `sigmahat` the estimate of the standard deviation.
Now if you call it with a second argument `alpha` it will give 4 outputs, the 2 estimates, and also the confidence intervals for each estimate:

```
[muhat,sigmahat,muci,sigmaci] = normfit(X,alpha)
```

`muci` contains are the confidence interval on the mean and `sigmaci` the confidence interval on the standard deviation.

Example:

```
>>a=randn(1,100);
>>[muhat,sigmahat,muci,sigmaci] = normfit(a,.01);
>>sigmaci

sigmaci =
    0.8550
    1.2360
```

So P(0.8550< `sigma`< 1.2360) = 1-0.1.

`sigma_2` is the variance so by simply squaring `sigmaci` you have the confidence interval on `sigma_2`:

```
>>sigma_2ci=sigmaci.^2
sigma_2ci =

0.7310    1.5277
```

and P(0.7310< `sigma_2`< 1.5277) = 1-0.1.